# Get ContentTypeId In NewForm.aspx URL QueryString

Tags: content-type, 2007, jquery, javascript

I've been trying to access the ContentTypeId in the NewForm.aspx querystring. Knowing that will allow me to set up conditional statements to display information specific to a Content Type. My question:

**Does anyone have some code to share that demonstrates, with jQuery or javascript, how to get the value of ContentTypeId parameter in the querystring?**

Thanks in advance!

Arnold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, without jQuery:

```
function querySt(stKey) {
    stQString = window.location.search.substring(1);
    arKeyValues = stQString.split("&");
    for (i = 0; i < arKeyValues.length; i++) {
        arPairs = arKeyValues[i].split("=");
        if (arPairs[0] == stKey) {
            return arPairs[1];
        }
    }
};

var contentTypeId = querySt("ContentTypeId");
```

Comment: Thanks guys!

Sebastien, I'm sure your code works in 99% of cases, but for some reason, that code breaks my jQuery floating and draggable. I tried using that very code snippet yesterday...but no joy.

Jim Bob, your javascript worked perfectly, so I'm accepting your answer.

However, you guys should check this out:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itaysk/archive/2008/11/30/getting-query-string-parameters-with-javascript-in-sharepoint.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Itay uses a SharePoint function that's not well-documented to get querystring parameters. Works well.

-Arn

Answer (score 1):

With the following jQuery extension (see [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)), you could use the following code to get your ContentTypeId :

```
var contentTypeId = $.query.get('ContentTypeId');
```